# Python while loop in try except instruction

Tags: python, while-loop, try-except

I have simple code:

```
def simpleMethod():
    try:
        list_to_app = []                                                                                  
        number_of_a = input('\nHow many a you want to create? ')
        number_of_a = int(number_of_a)
        for i in range(number_of_a):                                                           
            user_a = input('\nPlease type here some track: ')
            list_to_app.append(user_a.lower())                                          
    except ValueError:
        stderr.write('Type error - please provide an integer character')
simpleMethod()
```

I do not want to use something like `while True:...`
How to make some loop (I think while will be fine in this case) for this kind of flow:

1. user types non-integer
2. program shows `Type error - please provide an integer character`
3. program goes back to 1. step

This is simple method but I'm stuck.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a `while` loop?  That is indeed the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Why not "while True"? Is this some homework with questionable restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `while True` loop to repeat the `try` block until it can successfully `break`.  You probably also want to return the list you're building so that the caller can access it:

```
def simpleMethod():
    list_to_app = []  

    while True:
        try:
            number_of_a = input('\nHow many a you want to create? ')
            number_of_a = int(number_of_a)
            break
        except ValueError:
            stderr.write('Type error - please provide an integer character')

    for i in range(number_of_a):                                                           
        user_a = input('\nPlease type here some track: ')
        list_to_app.append(user_a.lower())

    return list_to_app  # no point building a list you don't return!                          

tracks = simpleMethod()
```

A simpler way to build a list is a comprehension -- you can actually put almost the entire function in a single comprehension statement within that `while`, since the exception will raise to the outer loop.  You might also want to make the function name more descriptive:

```
from typing import List

def get_user_tracks() -> List[str]:
    """Prompt the user for a list of tracks."""
    while True:
        try:
            return [
                input('\nPlease type here some track: ') 
                for _ in range(int(input('\nHow many a you want to create? ')))
            ]
        except ValueError:
            stderr.write('Type error - please provide an integer character')

tracks = get_user_tracks()
```